# How to generalize or parameterize the SQL query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a problem with my employee_det table, where I am categorizing year wise active employee status. 
for example1: an employee joined in 01-01-2017 and released from company in 02-02-2018 then he/she fall under 2017 bucket.

example2: If an employee joined in 01-02-2018 and released in 01-15-2019 then he will be under 2018 bucket.

if an employee joined in 01-01-2017 and he is still continuing in company then he must fall under 2019.

I have written the following query and which is giving me accurate results, but next year I need to add one more entry in WHERE condition, instead of that is there is any generalized way to solve this.

```
select emp_id, ename, year(effective_start_date) as year_bucket 
from employee_det 
where worker_status = 'Active' 
  and manager_name like '%srinivas%'
  and (
        ( date(effective_start_date) <= '2017-12-31' 
         and date(effective_end_date)>='2017-12-31' ) 
        or 
        ( date(effective_start_date) <= '2018-12-31' 
         and date(effective_end_date)>='2018-12-31' ) 
        or
        ( date(effective_start_date) <= current_date() 
         and date(effective_end_date)>=current_date()
      )
```

Comment: i am not sure why you need all those WHERE clauses. Looks to me you don't need them at all. Can you elaborate on your logic here.

Comment: Hi Mikhail, basically i am performing UNION operation with 2017 , 2018 and 2019 data who are active employees. for ex: if an employee joined in jan 2017 and resigned in dec 2017 then he should not populate in 2017 bucket, if he/she joined in jan 2017 and resigned in jan 2018 then he/she must fall under 2017 employee count. so instead of UNION every year i need generic way of classification, so that i cannot add where condition every year

Comment: do you mean that such employee should not appear in any bucket? because he/she joined and left in the same very year? please confirm.

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT emp_id, ename,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM IF(effective_end_date >= CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE, effective_start_date)) year_bucket
FROM `project.dataset.employee_det`
WHERE worker_status = 'Active' 
AND manager_name LIKE '%srinivas%'
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.employee_det` AS (
  SELECT 1 emp_id, 'employee1' ename, DATE '2017-01-01' effective_start_date, DATE '2018-02-02' effective_end_date, 'Active' worker_status, 'srinivas' manager_name UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'employee2', '2018-01-02', '2019-01-15', 'Active', 'srinivas' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'employee3', '2017-01-01', '2019-04-15', 'Active', 'srinivas' 
)
SELECT emp_id, ename,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM IF(effective_end_date >= CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE, effective_start_date)) year_bucket
FROM `project.dataset.employee_det`
WHERE worker_status = 'Active' 
AND manager_name LIKE '%srinivas%'
```

with result

```
Row emp_id  ename       year_bucket  
1   1       employee1   2017     
2   2       employee2   2018     
3   3       employee3   2019
```

> Update - excluding employees whose start and end YEAR is the same

You can just use one "generic" clause as below

```
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM effective_start_date) != EXTRACT(YEAR FROM effective_end_date)
```

so, the whole query now will be as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.employee_det` AS (
  SELECT 1 emp_id, 'employee1' ename, DATE '2017-01-01' effective_start_date, DATE '2018-02-02' effective_end_date, 'Active' worker_status, 'srinivas' manager_name UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'employee2', '2018-01-02', '2019-01-15', 'Active', 'srinivas' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'employee3', '2017-01-01', '2019-04-15', 'Active', 'srinivas' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'employee4', '2017-01-01', '2017-04-15', 'Active', 'srinivas' 
)
SELECT emp_id, ename,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM IF(effective_end_date >= CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE, effective_start_date)) year_bucket
FROM `project.dataset.employee_det`
WHERE worker_status = 'Active' 
AND manager_name LIKE '%srinivas%'
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM effective_start_date) != EXTRACT(YEAR FROM effective_end_date)
```

with result

```
Row emp_id  ename       year_bucket  
1   1       employee1   2017     
2   2       employee2   2018     
3   3       employee3   2019
```

as you can see - employee4 is not included in any bucket

Comment: Thanks a lot Mikhail!! It helped me

Comment: Hi Mikhail, there is a small correction in the logic required, if you observe the employee3 record., it should fall under 2017 bucket, but it is showing as 2019. could you please tell me how to correct this

Comment: based on the logic you explained in your question - if end date is greater than current date it means that employee is still in effect and it should be in the year of end date. at least that is how I got it from your question

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want the start year for employees who have ended and the current year for active employees.  So:

```
select emp_id, ename,
       (case when effective_end_date > current_date
             then year(current_date)
             else year(effective_start_date)
        end) as year_bucket
from employee_det
where worker_status = 'Active' and
      manager_name like '%srinivas%';
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for reply.! when 2020 came into picture i need to add one more where condition like date(effective_start_date)<='2019-12-31' and date(effective_end_Date)>='2019-12-31'..! every year i need to add one more condition, instead of that is there any way to generalize this "where condition"

Comment: simply says, i dont want to use hardcoaded values like '2017-12-31' in my where clause of the query

Comment: @SrinivasCh . . . This doesn't have hardcoded values.  It implements the logic described at the beginning of the answer.